# Calculate Sum using ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, arraylist

I'm creating a SpringServiceImpl class where it will the total debit amount inside the List. However, I got an error: `The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) List<GeneralLedgerEntity>, GeneralLedgerEntity`

```
List<GeneralLedgerEntity> calculateResult = new ArrayList<>();
for(GeneralLedgerEntity credit : calculateResult){
    calculateResult += credit;
    return calculateResult;
}
```

what should be the option for this?

Comment: `calculateResult` is your list, i think you want to have a numeric value here

Comment: Please correct your question, you cannot do += for a arraylist. I guess you have forgotten java, and i don't know what people are assuming and answering your question

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Either calculate a total, but you've not created a numeric var to store a total in, or make a list of all the `GeneralLedgerEntity`'s, but you're looping through an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sum `GeneralLedgerEntity` objects, Java doesn't have operator overloading (except for Strings).

What you need is to add the value this objects holds, for example if you have a field called `debitAmount` in the `GeneralLedgerEntity` class then do:

`calculateResult += credit.debitAmount`

And also you have a return statement in your `for` loop, that doesn't make sense, it's gonna be executed only once, move the return statement after the loop.

Comment: `calculateResult` is a List<>, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the + operator in Java. Instead, you would have to implement `plus` or `add` method in your SpringServiceImpl class.

```
class Point{
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point add(Point other){
        this.x += other.x;
        this.y += other.y;
        return this;
    }
}
```

usage

```
Point a = new Point(1,1);
Point b = new Point(2,2);
a.add(b);
```